# Please explain subtleties of read([] bytes)

Tags: java

Can you explain one thihg, when a do something like that:

```
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(path1);
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(path2);
byte[] array=new byte[fis1.available()+fis2.available()];
```

And if i want to write bytes to array :

```
fis2.read(array);
fis1.read(array);
```

What it will (method read()) do? It will write ALL bytes to array from both streams or no?
How bytes and in what order will be written in the array? Didnt find in spec and docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`read(byte[] b)` method javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) says:

> Reads up to `b.length` bytes of data from this input stream into an array of bytes. This method blocks until some input is available.
>
> **Returns**:    the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the file has been reached.

What it means is it reads "some" number of bytes into the beginning of the array.

How many bytes does it read? The method returns the number of bytes it read. It reads at most the full length of the array, but it will likely be an amount in the range of a few kilobytes at most. The exact details depend on the operating system and file system implementation.

It does not read all bytes from the file, and it does not guarantee the byte array is filled entirely. If you call it twice, it does not return the same data twice.